# How to avoid ORA-00060 (deadlock detected) error when updating Oracle table on Spark

Tags: sql, oracle, scala, apache-spark, deadlock

I have a weird error in my spark job and I would use some explanation if possible.

So, my Spark job loads data from a Hive table, transform it into a Dataframe and then updates an already existing Oracle table based on some columns.

When the dataframe is not very huge, the job runs with no problems. 
When the dataframe is pretty huge, the job runs for several hours and then stops with an Oracle error:

```
exception caught: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 104 in stage 43.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 104.3 in stage 43.0 (TID 5937, lxpbda55.ra1.intra.groupama.fr, executor 227): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

This is how my code works:

```
//This is where the error appears
modification(df_Delta_Modif, champs, conditions, cstProp)

//This is its definition
def modification(df: DataFrame, champs: List[String], conditions: List[String], cstProp: java.util.Properties) {
    val url = Parametre_mod.oracleUrl
    val options: JDBCOptions = new JDBCOptions(Map("url" -> url, "dbtable" -> Parametre_mod.targetTableBase, "user" -> Parametre_mod.oracleUser,
      "password" -> Parametre_mod.oraclePassword, "driver" -> "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "batchSize" -> "30000"))
    Crud_mod.modifierbatch(df, options, champs, conditions)
  }

//This is the definition of modifierbatch. It starts with establishing a connection to Oracle.
//Which surely works because I use the same thing on other scripts and it works fine
def modifierbatch(df: DataFrame,
              options : JDBCOptions,
               champs: List[String],
               conditions: List[String]) {
    val url = options.url
    val tables = options.table
    val dialect = JdbcDialects_mod.get(url)
    val nullTypes: Array[Int] = df.schema.fields.map { field =>
      getJdbcType(field.dataType, dialect).jdbcNullType
    }
    val rddSchema = df.schema
    val getConnection: () => Connection = createConnectionFactory(options)
    val batchSize = options.batchSize
    val chainestmt = creerOdreSQLmodificationSimple(champs, conditions, tables) //definition below
    val listChamps: List[Int] = champs.map(rddSchema.fieldIndex):::conditions.map(rddSchema.fieldIndex)
    df.foreachPartition { iterator =>
      //savePartition(getConnection, table, iterator, rddSchema, nullTypes, batchSize, dialect)
      executePartition(getConnection, tables, iterator, rddSchema, nullTypes, batchSize, chainestmt, listChamps, dialect, 0, "")
    }
  }

//This is the definition of creerOdreSQLmodificationSimple
def creerOdreSQLmodificationSimple(listChamps: List[String], listCondition: List[String], tablecible: String): String = {
    val champs = listChamps.map(_.toUpperCase).mkString(" = ?, ")
    val condition = listCondition.map(_.toUpperCase).mkString(" = ? and ")

    s"""UPDATE ${tablecible} SET ${champs} = ? WHERE ${condition} = ?"""
  }
```

So as you can see the principal is not very complicated. I just execute an Oracle function (update) using a batch. I don't know what causes the deadlock problem. I did not use any repartition in Spark.

Please let me know if you need further details. Thank you

Comment: Every Oracle deadlock generates a trace file that explains what statements and objects were involved with the deadlock.  The relevant code and objects are not always obvious - the problem may have been caused by something weird like using bitmap indexes on transactional tables, or another unexpected statement running at the same time.  Look at the alert log and it will point to where the trace file was generated (ask your DBA if you don't have access to the server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `df.foreachPartition`, it looks like the database access is being done on multiple parallel connections.

If so, there must be conditions in each partition that update the same rows.

Your options are:

1. Get rid of the overlap so that no two updates update the same row(s).
2. If you can't do that, arrange things so that all updates affecting a given row are guaranteed to be in the same "partition".
3. If you can't do that, sort the condition values before processing them.  E.g., if your conditions are like `column1 = ? and column2 = ?` and your values set is { (1, 'R'), (5, 'Q'), (1,'B'), (2, 'Z') }, then sort them (1,'B')->(1,'R')->(2,'Z')->(5,'Q').  It actually doesn't matter how you sort them as long as the sort order is unambiguous (no ties) and all partitions sort their conditions the same way.
4. Don't use `foreachPartition` (i.e., don't try to run in parallel).  Actually this is just a variant of #2 above.

Sorting the work, as per option 3, will avoid the deadlock, but you'll lose much of the benefit of running in parallel (since some partitions will block others).